# Is there any application on Ubuntu equivalent to fedora's 'Connect To'?

Tags: software-recommendation, ssh, openssh

On `Fedora 14` I use to use an app called 'Connect To' (I think it was default app) to make SSH connections. It was GUI based SSH connection tool.

Now I have migrated to `Ubuntu` (11.10 to be precise). I use terminal based `OpenSSH`. OpenSSH is pretty good but sometimes I wish it was GUI app. I have tried a few but none do the job like 'Connect To' on fedora.

Is there any `Connect To` equvalent on Ubuntu ?

Comment: @JorgeCastro I believe the linked question is in regards to using SSHFS, and that Mr Ghimire is referring to actually using the remote shell function of SSH, although I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Remmina](http://remmina.sourceforge.net/) would be a good solution. I believe it ships with 12.04, but I think you have to manually install it on 11.10.

```
sudo apt-get install remmina
```

Or, just install it from the Ubuntu Software Center:

[image: Install via the software center]

It also works with VNC, RDP, NX and SFTP.